# Why is $F(a,b) = G(a,b, \bar F (a,b) )$ unique if $\bar F (a,b)$ is a sequence number applied to each element of a sequence?

Tags: functions, logic, computability

I was reading [these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf) and on page 88 (of the paper version) it said:

[image]

however it wasn't clear to me why the function would be unique (or why it mattered). It seems entirely possible depending on the definition of $G$ that it might not be unique. Also, how does the explanation of making the explicit point by point what $F$ is explain anything? **I think that is the key point I don't understand.**

Comment: I still don't know why uniqueness is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty intuitively clear why $F$ is uniquely defined. If you want to know what $F(a,b)$ is for any $a$ and $b$, you simply apply the $F(a,b+1)$ equation repeatedly until $b=0$ and then you apply the $F(a,0)$ equation. This will unfold $F(a,b)$ out into a $b$-deep nested applications of $G$ to itself. Now, we'll still have occurrences of $F$ in this unfolded expression, but since they are always applied to smaller values of $b$ we can use strong induction to show that they too can be rewritten in terms of $G$ only. The end result is that $F(a,b)$ is defined as an expression solely in terms of $G$, $a$, and $b$. If you do the proof, you'll find that strong induction fits *extremely* nicely. This is no surprise as this is the computational analogue of strong induction (with parameters) itself.

Comment: why is uniqueness obvious? Thats usually requires proof.